# How to delete files uploaded to s3 using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I want to stop uploading a file and also delete the uploaded files from s3 on clicking delete button. The code works but this logs output in the console that the delete failed with net:err_failed.

Below is the code,

```
handle_upload = () => { 
    this.upload(item.id); 
}

upload = () => {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: upload_definition.upload.region,
        accessKeyId: upload_definition.upload.credentials.access_key_id,
        secretAccessKey: upload_definition.upload.credentials.secret_access_key,
        sessionToken: upload_definition.upload.credentials.session_token,
    });

    const upload = new S3.ManagedUpload({
        params: {
            Bucket: upload_definition.upload.bucket_name,
            Key: upload_definition.upload.prefix + file.name,
            Body: file,
            leavePartsOnError: true,
        },
     });

     this.upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function (some_var) {
         /*some content*/
     });

     try {
         await this.upload.promise();
     } catch (error) {
         this.setState({failed: true});
         return;
     }

 }

 handle_delete = ()  => {
     delete_item();//my api to delete the item
}

 render = () => {
     return (
         <button onclick={this.handle_delete}>Delete</button>
      )
  }
```

I am not sure how to delete files from s3 after upload...on clicking delete button within handle_delete i call api to delete the item. was thinking to abort the upload and when aborting call the delete version.

Tried something like below and doesnt work. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

```
handle_upload = () => { 
    this.upload(item.id); 
}

upload = () => {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: upload_definition.upload.region,
        accessKeyId: upload_definition.upload.credentials.access_key_id,
        secretAccessKey: upload_definition.upload.credentials.secret_access_key,
        sessionToken: upload_definition.upload.credentials.session_token,
    });

    this.upload = new S3.ManagedUpload({
        params: {
            Bucket: upload_definition.upload.bucket_name,
            Key: upload_definition.upload.prefix + file.name,
            Body: file,
            leavePartsOnError: true,
        },
     });

     this.upload.on('httpUploadProgress', function (some_var) {
         /*somecontent*/
     });

     try {
         await this.upload.promise();
     } catch (error) {
         this.setState({failed: true});
         return;
     }

 }

 handle_delete = async()  => {
     await this.upload.abort();
     delete_item();//my api to delete the item
}
```

How can i delete the uploaded files to s3 from frontend..thanks.

Comment: the problem seems to be in the delete function and the only thing you do not post is the delete function.

Comment: thanks. i should have put the leavePartsOnError outside params and it works.